# Git Merge Out of Sync Repos

Tags: git, version-control

I started using git to track my customizations to a 3rd party web app. I interface with consultants that have been using git to track their changes for a while. I'll try to make this easy to understand.

- I have a copy of an export from one of our environments
- I started a repository using the export as a base [LOCAL] and have been committing to it regularly
- The consultants have their own repository that is up to date (excludes my changes) [3RDPARTY]
- I've forked their git repo [REMOTE]

Now from here all I want to do is go through and merge all the files that are different between **[LOCAL]** and **[REMOTE]**.

I don't care about the branches or history I currently have in LOCAL. I only care about using REMOTE from now on and sending/receiving pull requests to interact with the consultants.

How do you recommend I can do this?  I tried creating a new branch on LOCAL and overwriting all the files with the updated files from 3RDPARTY. Then I was hoping a merge between that new branch and my regular dev branch would give me a conflict so I could easily merge them all with KDiff3 but instead it just automerged and overwrote all my changes instead.

Comment: Maybe a rebase is what you are looking for. It would allow you to apply your new commits on top of their new commits (or vice versa if you so please, although I don't know if that sounds too desirable). But I might misunderstand what you are aiming for. See `git help rebase`; the documentation is also nice (I thought).

Comment: I'm not sure that would work since LOCAL has absolutely no ties to 3RDPARTY or REMOTE? Or could you describe in more detail? I've read about rebase and all of the examples act as at one time sharing a common parent commit in the repo. LOCAL is its own totally disconnected repo.

Comment: Ah, okay. I thought you had made a fork from [REMOTE] (and thus [3RDPARRTY]), so that you once had a common parent commit. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tried to copy all the files over and just get a merge but it didn't work.  That should work, but I think you may need to follow some different steps which I'll try to explain.

There should be a tag, or checking in `3RDPARTY` that was identical to a checkin point in your export environment which is the first checkin to `LOCAL`.  I will call this checkin `MERGE_BASE`. So try these steps:

- First of all do `git checkout master` on `REMOTE` and make sure it is
  up to date with `3RDPARTY` with `git pull origin`.
- In `REMOTE` `git branch mergeb <MERGE_BASE>`  `<MERGE_BASE>` is the
  checkin I spoke about in the history that is identical, or as close
  as identical, to what you would have in your initial creation of
  `LOCAL`.
- Copy the source for your most up to date version in `LOCAL` directly
  over top the files in your `mergeb` branch we just created in
  `REMOTE`. DONOT copy the .git directory!
- In `REMOTE` on branch `mergeb` use `git add` to make sure all your
  changes are applied to the git index and then run `git commit`.  Now
  your `REMOTE` `mergeb` branch should have identical source to what is
  in `LOCAL`. (you could use git remotes to do this with your LOCAL
  changes, but since you don't care about history I recommend just
  doing it this way to simplify the process).
- Checkout the master branch again `git checkout master`.
- At this point create a new branch that you will use to contribute to
  them.. do `git checkout -b remote_work`.
- Now, simply merge the `mergeb` branch into your `remote_work` branch
  with `git merge --no-ff mergeb`.  At this point you will probably
  have all the conflicting merges with their work and your work to
  resolve.

Once you finish this process and commit the work to your branch you should be now in the exact state you wanted.

After all of this, if you want all your work to appear as if you started with what is currently in `3RDPARTY` while on the `remote_work` branch on `REMOTE` simply do `git rebase master`.

From then on out I would keep master on `REMOTE` synced with their `3RDPARTY` repo and keep your changes which hasn't been pulled into `3RDPARTY` in the `remote_work` or other various branches on the `REMOTE` repo.

Let me know if this process works out for you.