# Find the closest git merge base

Tags: git, merge, diff

Given a git repository that have been forked and both fork evolved. One of them **hasn't been forked regularly with git neither developped under VCS** (ie it's text file as is).

The final objective is to merge this two versions of the same code into the original repository. But to do so effeciently (ie. avoid mistakes and merge conflicts resolution) **the fork point has to be found**. At least somewhere not to far away from the original fork point.

After that it will be relatively easy to merge both versions as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8823654/git-merge-out-of-sync-repos). The point is to find:

> [...] the checkin [...] in the history that is identical, or as close as identical [...]

I've been trying to use `git bisect` combinated with the diff size (eg something like `diff -r vcs-sources novcs-sources | wc -l`) between the two sources directories to find where it has the less differencies and consider this as the fork point. But this is not a linear function so bisection is not adapted here and manual search is not an option since the the amount of commits are pretty huge.

Do you have any idea on how to do this ?

Comment: Try with a bash script that will calculate differences between revisions (say, counted in lines) and provide you with the closest revisions. That should only take minutes to write and given git's speed, it shouldn't take you that long to get the revisions you need.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... are you saying you *don't* have a git history for the fork, that would trace back to the fork point?

Comment: If the two repositories were directly related (i.e., one was a clone of the other or both were clones of some common ancestor) *and* neither has had all its history rewritten, some of the hash IDs for commits will be shared across the two repositories. In this case, you can simply glue the two commit DAGs together, by `git fetch`ing the contents of both repos into one big common repo, and then use the normal graph algorithms, i.e., `git merge-base`. If *not*, there's no single correct answer.

Comment: @torek, @mark-adelsberger, that the point of the question, I'll tried to make it clearer: For one of the sources I have the entire git history (from before it where "forked") and the other that diverged hasn't been developped under CVS.
@Edmundo, I'll try with a bash script, how would you iterate along the branch ? just step by step using `git checkout HEAD^1`?

Comment: I'm not sure why you are bringing CVS into it (CVS vs Git is the proverbial 
"bringing a knife to a gun fight" :-) ). Perhaps, based on question edit, it was a typo for "VCS", Version Control Software. Anyway, the word "fork" seems to just be muddying the water here as it made it sound like a GitHub fork-button `git clone` step. (BTW @<name> only works for one @ so I'm the only one who got a message from StackOverflow about your comment.)